# How to write test case for rxjs interval in angular 8?

Tags: angular, rxjs, intervals, testcase

I have one method "intervalCall()" into app.component.ts and sending the request every 60 seconds using rxjs interval, so want to test case for it for spect file, below is the method.

```
intervalCall() {
    interval(60 * 1000)
      .pipe(mergeMap(() => this.XYZService.XYZmethod()))
      .subscribe((data: StatusDependents) => {
        if (data.status === 'UP') {
          location.reload();
        }
      });
  }
```

this.XYZService.XYZmethod() is my service call which I am sending every 60 seconds.

I have write down below test case, still getting error with **1 periodic timer(s) still in the queue.**

```
 describe('#intervalCall', () => {
    it('should call intervalCall method when status is UP', fakeAsync(() => {
      const statusData: StatusDependents = { status: 'UP' };
      const statusSpy = jest.spyOn(userService, 'statusDependents').mockReturnValue(of(statusData));
      component.intervalCall();
      fixture.detectChanges();
      tick(180500);
      expect(statusSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
      flush();
    }));
  });
```

Comment: I'm not sure this code does what you think it should. I'm thinking you should mock `this.XYZService.XYZMethod` and then test that it gets called three times in three minutes. As a unit testing rule, your test code shouldn't *actually* call `this.XYZService.XYZmethod`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use fakeAsync. See how it's used here: https://v8.angular.io/guide/testing

The main advantage I've found is that you aren't waiting real seconds while unit testing, you can use `tick(180500)` to jump ahead 3 minutes and ½ seconds instantly.

Comment: Thanks @JSmart523 I have write down below test case and added tick(180500)

describe('#intervalCall', () => {
    it('should call intervalCall method when status is UP', fakeAsync(() => {
      const statusData: StatusDependents = { status: 'UP' };
      const statusSpy = jest.spyOn(userService, 'statusDependents').mockReturnValue(of(statusData));
      component.intervalCall();
      fixture.detectChanges();
      tick(180500);
      expect(statusSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
      flush();
    }));
  });

but still get one error saying "1 periodic timer(s) still in the queue."

Comment: I have edited my question with test case for better understanding with test case.

Comment: I haven't had experience with that error but my *guess* is that you still have a subscribed observable still emitting, so `flush()` keeps trying to finish all events and (appropriately) gives up and throws an error. To fix, you'll have to (and definitely should in any case) cause your observable in `intervalCall` to complete or be unsubscribed when an `ngOnDestroy` method is called, then change your unit testing to call the `ngOnDestroy` method before you `flush()`. See https://digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/angular-takeuntil-rxjs-unsubscribe for an explanation.